# Generate table from "awk" command of different files in a bash program?

Tags: bash, awk, datatable

I need to make a table of numbers, where these numbers were obtained from different files, my code is

```
#!/bin/sh
for K in 1.7e-2; do 
    dir0=Kn_${K};
    for P in 1.4365 2.904; do
        dir1=P${P};
            for r in 0.30 0.35; do
                dir2=${r};
                awk '/result is =/{print $NF}' ./First/${dir0}/${dir1}/R\=${dir2}/Results.dat
            done;
    done;
done;
exit;
```

I obtain as

```
1
2
3
4
```

but I need

```
1   3
2   4
```

I was reading some posts on this topic, but these topic are about on files and not that the data were generated.

Thanks for your help and support

Comment: just pipe the output to `pr -2ts$'\t'`

Comment: @karakfa I don't think that will work for multiple pages though

Comment: @andlrc what are multiple pages?

Comment: @karakfa See `man pr` specifically the `-l` option, and consider the following example `seq 1000 | pr -2ts`

Comment: @andlrc I'm very familiar with `pr`.  I don't see how multiple pages are applicable here since at most the product of loop counter number of lines will be there.  Even there are thousands you can set the page length arbitrarily long so there won't be multiple pages.

Comment: Thank you @karakfa  for your suggestion,
With executing the option you gave me
| pr -4ts $ '\ t'
I see that the numbers are interleaved, since the first line, the third, the fifth, the seventh are chosen and in the next line they are the second, the fourth, the sixth, the eighth.

I need is, first second Third Fourth
and the other line, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth.

Do you  know if the options are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the data as,

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Wit the pipe  `pr -4ts $ '\ t'` (thanks @karakfa)

I obtained

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

then with a script to transpose as,

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {
    for (j =1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str" "a[i,j];
        }
        print str   
    }
}' $1
```

I obtained

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
```

I have a problem with interspersed the numbers,

I need

```
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
```

But I don't know, what is the problem with command `pr` and its options?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why did you chose 4 columns?  You want 2 as in my suggestion.  Just use the one in the comment as is.

Comment: @karakfa, i need 4  rows and 2 columns because at script at my  computer to generate the data, have loop (rows) 0.30..0.05..1, I wrote an example as a matrix 2x2, and I wanted to extrapolate your suggestion to my needs, rows 15, and columns 120, but I couldn't. Please, can you help me?

Comment: @karakfa, To know if I am understanding correctly, I am implementing it to a second example, 4 rows and 2 columns. And it was when I noticed my mistake.

Comment: you specify the number of columns.  First try for the sample data with 2 to get your desired output.  For 120 you may hit some page size constraints where you may need to change the width and length.

Comment: @karakfa, but I don't understand why in the second example (4 rows and 2 columns), the command pr, already orders the rows, skipping the data.

Comment: @karakfa, I solved (15 rows and 5 columns), with your exact suggestion. Without any change, thanks